# JSch: Run command after Multi-Level ssh

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I am using JSch to run some commands after multi-level ssh:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String user="User0";
    String ip="IP0";
    int port=22;
    String password="Password0";
            JSch jsch= new JSch();
            Session session=null;
            ChannelExec channel=null;
            try {
                session=(jsch.getSession(user, ip, port));
                session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
                session.setPassword(password);
                session.connect();
                String dir=Reomte_DIR;  
                String cmd1=SomeComplexCommand;
                String cmd2=SomeMoreComplexCommand;
                channel = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
                channel.setInputStream(null);
                channel.setCommand("ssh User1@IP1_PasswordLessLogin;ssh User2@IP2_PasswordLessLogin; "+cmd1+" ; "+cmd2+" ;");
                channel.setPty(true);
                channel.connect(4000);
                String res = null;
                    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(channel.getInputStream()));
                    BufferedReader error = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(channel.getErrStream()));
                    if ((res = error.readLine()) == null) {
                        res = input.readLine()+input.readLine()+input.readLine()+input.readLine();
                    } else {

                        res = "-1";
                    }
                System.out.println("result:"+res);

            } catch (JSchException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                channel.disconnect();
                session.disconnect();
            }       
        }
```

but it doesn't give desired result.

Infact `channel.getInputStream()` hangs. If I remove multilevel ssh, everything works fine!
Am i doing something wrong??

I got some hint from: [Multi-level SSH login in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163638/multi-level-ssh-login-in-java) and [Multiple commands using JSch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17352764/multiple-commands-using-jsch) but i am not able to get my code running.

Comment: Your command is wrong, did you try it on command line at all first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command is wrong.

Your command will execute the first command `ssh User1@IP1_PasswordLessLogin`.

And then it will wait for it to finish before executing the second command.

- The first `ssh` command never finishes, as it will forever keep waiting for user to type commands.
- Even if the first `ssh` ever finished, the second `ssh` would be executed on the initial host, not one the `IP1`.

---

You need something like this:

```pascal
ssh User1@IP1_PasswordLessLogin ssh User2@IP2_PasswordLessLogin "<cmd1> ; <cmd2>"
```

This tells the first `ssh` to execute the second `ssh` on the `IP1`; and the second `ssh` to execute the `<cmd1> ; <cmd2>` on the `IP2`.